# Links to plugin files not resolving

Tags: plugins

Has anyone seen an issue where links to plugin files can't be resolved and results in 404 errors?

For example, I have a plugin that drops a page template into the active theme directory, and this template file references a reset.css file. The reset.css file is found in the /wp-contet/plugins/[plugin-name]/templates folder.

Everything is fine until you create a new page with the template and then view the page; the layout is wrong. When viewing the source, I see that the link to the reset.css file is correct (http://site.com/wp-content/plugins/plugin-name/templates/reset.css), but when I put that URL in the browser it results in a "page not found" error.

I've tried deactivating other plugins, checked permissions, and turned on the debug log, but so far nothing has helped.

Any ideas?
o

Comment: are you 100% sure this file exists on your server?

Comment: Please add link to live site with this issue, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that 9 times out of 10, a 404 for a direct link to a file is because the file isn't actually there.

Try placing a text file (or html or whatever) in the same directory as your css file and see if you can hit it with a browser (by copying/pasting the URL to your css file and just replacing the filename). Be very careful to make sure you're visiting the same directory during this test. If you can't get to the test file, you've got the wrong path altogether.

If you're on Apache, it shouldn't be a permissions issue. You'd get a 403 rather than the WordPress 404. I've seen this be a permissions issue on IIS though. If you're on IIS, right-click on the file, go to the security tab, and make sure the 'everyone' user has full control (just as a test). If this fixes your problem, it's a perms issue, and you'll have to figure out what level of security to scale back to.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out the issue was due to my misunderstanding of how wordpress.org packages the plugin upon download. That caused some path issues I was not aware of, but I've tracked them down and fixed them. Thanks anyway guys.

Comment: For the benefit of others with the same problem can you please explain your solution?